# Find all the critical points

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Define $H:\mathbb{R}^3$$ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $H(x,y,z)=x+y+z.$

Determine all critical points of $h : S \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where
$S:= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 |x^2 + y^2 = z^2 +1\}$ and $h = H_{|S}$.

I am a little lost on how to begin, I know that the critical points of $H$ are all points $x$ such that $H’(x) = 0$. But i am not sure how to find the critical points of $h$.

Comment: $H'$ refers to like $\nabla H$ ?

Answer (score 4):

We use the Lagrange multipliers method. Let us set
$$L(x, y, z, \lambda) = x + y + z + \lambda(x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1).$$
We must solve the equation $\nabla_{x, y, z, \lambda} L = 0$. This is given by the system
$$
\begin{cases}
1 + 2\lambda x = 0, \\
1 + 2\lambda y = 0,\\
1 - 2\lambda z = 0,\\
x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - 1 = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Using only the first three equations we get $x = y = - z$ (note that $\lambda \neq 0$ otherwise $1 = 0$). Using the last equation you can easily find the value of the critical points.

Comment: This we can do because S is a smooth 2-dimensional submanifold